# Prove that the unit disk is open

Tags: general-topology

This isn't a homework question.  For some reason, I'm having trouble proving this statement, even though it should be elementary.

**The question is: If we call the open unit disk $D$ (i.e., $D = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} < 1 \}$), then I want to prove that $D$ is open.**

I want to prove this by finding for each element in $D$ an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball around the point of radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $D$.

Here is my idea:  Let $(x^{*},y^{*}) \in D$.  Choose $\epsilon = \min{ \{ |x^{*} - 1|, |x^{*} + 1|, |y^{*} - 1|, |y^{*} + 1|    \} }$.  Now, I want to show that if $(x, y) \in B( (x^{*}, y^{*}), \epsilon)$, then $(x, y) \in D$, that is, $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} < 1$.  I can't seem to figure out why $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} < 1$ using the $\epsilon$ I've chosen.

Comment: Have you tried using the triangle inequality at all?

Comment: I'm getting thrown off by relating the metric for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the metric used to construct $\epsilon$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of $\epsilon$ will work, but it is a cumbersome choice and it will just make your work harder.

Some geometric intuition will help in finding a more natural and useful choice of $\epsilon$. Your choice of $\epsilon$ has a geometric meaning: it is the shortest distance between $(x^*,y^*)$ and the boundary of the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Why not instead choose $\epsilon$ to be the shortest distance between $(x^*,y^*)$ and the boundary of the disc $D$? Namely 
$$\epsilon = 1 - \sqrt{(x^*)^2 + (y^*)^2}
$$
That number is just the length of the radial segment that connects $(x^*,y^*)$ to the boundary of $D$.

And now just apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: When I first considered using the $\epsilon$ you suggested, I started to think we don't know that $\epsilon$ will always be non-zero, but I guess we *do* know that because the point is not on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would help to consider the one-dimensional case, and the triangle inequality.

Say we have a point $x \in (-1,1)$, and want to find a $r$ such that $(x-r,x+r) \subset (-1,1)$; e.g. $|x-r| < 1$, and $|x+r| < 1$. Try applying the triangle inequality here, and you will notice $|x|$ is the important part.

Try applying the same calculations to the 2-dimensional case, again using $|p| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and see what you get!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the fact that $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous and your set is $f^{-1}((-\infty,1))$ and therefore open?